# Ho to remove the duplicate id in css file

Tags: html, css

Here i have so many pages. I called pagestyles  in one css as template.css
Its very difficult to find the duplicate id and removing the duplicate id's.
Please tell any solution regarding this.

```
#p11-textid6064
{
    position:absolute;
    top:165.89595890999973px;
    left:506.60787334800006px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
..
..
#p11-textid6064
{
    position:absolute;
    top:185px;
    left:508px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

...
...
#p11-textid6064
{
    position:absolute;
    top:565px;
    left:50px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

In the above css having same text ID's but different in different position. Please tell to remove the duplicates in this cases

Comment: Ctrl+F / select / delete... How can we answer: if there are duplicates, you have to analyze the one you want to keep and delete the other lines

Comment: @NicolasR the best answer

Comment: Using a JavaScript console, such as the one in Chrome, on the elements page you can examine the CSS rules for an element. If there are multiple conflicting entries you will see them there.

Comment: ya its right but here 1000 more pages ..

Comment: Welcome you with my +1 vote

Comment: 1000 pages and 1000 css included in pages??

Answer (score 0):

Find and Replace is really your best option here.

Depending on the development environment that you're using, it's possible to do a global find and replace across multiple files.  For example, if you were using visual studio you can use this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139eef4h.aspx, or if you're on a flavor of 'nix (or have cygwin installed on a windows environment) you can use some shell to do this for you, see here: http://diginit.wordpress.com/2008/04/23/unix-global-find-and-replace-using-find-grep-and-sed/